# Почему нельзя самому себе присуждать награду?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, конкурс

Допустим, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/973093/visual-studio-2019-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85) я отчаялся, что не было ответов и запустил конкурс, но чуть позже меня осенило и я нашел решение...

Почему нельзя самому себе назад залить репу?

Comment: Предполагаю такой алгоритм использования: вы постите вопрос, но вам никто не отвечает; вы открываете конкурс и теряете репу; конкурс привлекает отвечающих, вы получаете кучу интересных годных ответов; вы постите свой ответ (любого качества) и отмечаете его как правильный, тем самым вернув потраченную репу.

Comment: @АндрейNOP может быть. Но мне кажется, что если ответов нету и я сам себе ответил да еще и принял ответ, то не думаю, что можно заабузить конкурс.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а если ответ будет низкого качества, что бы вернуть себе карму, то всегда можно отметить его тревогой + понизить его рейтинг.

Comment: @iluxa1810, если награда была 500, то чтобы её компенсировать минусами на ответе, надо 250 минусов - нереально. Ну и отвечающие тоже могли рассчитывать на награду, а они её не получили. Так что такой вариант в любом случае оказывается нечестным, а откатить передачу репутации вроде нельзя, возможна только отмена конкурса модератором.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Правила такие. Как за галочку на собственном ответе не дают, так и репу конкурсную назад вернуть нельзя. Ну и чтоб не было накрутки просмотров на халяву, имхо. Если ответ хороший и нужный, то и так соберет плюсиков. Да и сам вопрос конкурсный больше очков собирает нежели такой же, но без конкурса.

Для автора вопроса объявление конкурса стоит воспринимать как возможность привлечь дополнительное внимание к проблеме. Так как внимание назад уже не вернуть, то и репу возвращать не положено. И по сути даже не обязательно награду кому-то другому вручать (в случае хорошего ответа система сама часть репы конкурса начислит, это для тех, кто забыл, что конкурс назначил вообще или ответ всё же не совсем решил проблему ТС).

Comment: В принципе модераторы могут отменять конкурс, только надо понять, правильно ли это делать и в каких случаях. Например, если нет чужих ответов и автор нашёл решение самостоятельно?

Comment: @Qwertiy модераторам должно быть виднее :)